# Ways to obtain bags

Tags: neverwinter

I have received the 24 slot bag from an early quest around lvl 10.
Are there other quests that reward bags?  Is it possible to purchase bags? To loot from a monster or chest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few quests that'll give you bags: http://www.arcgames.com/en/forums/neverwinter#/discussion/517007/bag-quests but they're neither particularly large nor particularly abundant.

Apart from that, the only ways to get bags are either through the Zen Store or the Auction House.

Also, take note the Bag of Holes that you can purchase is a 'gag' item and doesn't allow you to store even a single item in it.

Comment: +1, but so crappy that the answer to this is "Buy them with real money" though.... *sadface*

Comment: That's not entirely true (or perhaps isn't anymore). You can use astral diamonds to buy bags from the auction house. I only ever see two types there, and both seem to originate from something on the zen store, but you can earn them just the same.

Comment: Yeah I haven't played the game since pretty much this time last year, so I'm uncertain if things have changed. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

The last (3rd) bag you get from a quest is in Neverdeath.  It comes from Chettlebell and involves doing the clock dungeon place.  In order for that quest chain to pop up, though, you have to do the quest from the Doomguide that involves killing Bone Porters.  After that, new quests will show up with Chettlebell and Harper Windle.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy bags in the Auction House (AH), but they are so expensive no one can afford them early in the game.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase 24 slot bags with Zen in the Zen Market for real money, or by converting astral diamonds to Zen.

Comment: ...You dont even need to convert AD. You can buy them right off the AH lol

Comment: @user48258 for 1,000,000 gold go right ahead "lol"

Answer (score 1):

Tristopher Chettlebell in Neverdeath gives eventually a quest called Clockwork Guild Tomb what gives a 12 slot bag

Comment: Level 30 quest that is

Answer (score 1):

There is another bag available.
On the top of the UI is an Icon called Plus it's marked as a Flag,

Then a Menu opens called "Chronicles of the Sword Coast."

There's a Quest Line called "Order of the third Eye" from NPC Sybella (Protectors Enclave).

If you finish this Questline you get a 12 Slot Bag "Bestickter nimmervoller Beutel" (I don't know what it's called in English).

That makes three bags from questlines. So with the Starting inventory Bag (some People count that as a free Bag too) it should be 4 Bags.

Comment: I'd translate it as "embroidered bag of holding", as that seems to be the "bottomless" type of bag in d&d, though nimmervoller Beutel is literally "never-full bag". (If my German is up to par.)